# How do I make a MySQL insert query that "inserts if not exists"?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

```
INSERT INTO table('name') VALUES("abc") IF NOT EXISTS name='abc'
```

If abc doesn't exist in the name column, then insert it.  How can I write that query?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO table(name) VALUES('abc')
```

This will ignore the value if it already exists. Like pjotr said, this will require name to be a unique index.
[Source](http://bogdan.org.ua/2007/10/18/mysql-insert-if-not-exists-syntax.html)

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
insert into table('name') 
select 'abc'
where not exists (select 1 from table where name='abc')
```

Answer (score 2):

You may either use REPLACE ([syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replace.html), or, equivalent [INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)). This is more appropriate if there's more columns and you want to update the others for the given key.

Or the IGNORE modifier ([INSERT syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert.html)) along with a unique index for the 'name' column. In that case, the insert will be ignored if it violates the unique index, but won't throw an error. That's more appropriate if you don't want to change any values and just keep the record if it already exists.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it is testing it with an `IF`:

```
IF (select count(*) from table where name = 'abc') = 0
THEN
   INSERT INTO table('name') VALUES("abc")
```

Answer (score 0):

I would enforce the column as UNIQUE and catch the exception on the code side, if you have a unicity constraint on that field. Otherwise I tend to agree with other answers.

Answer (score 0):

I have Some Code...hope it will help you..

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO authors (author) VALUES ('$rec_fic_author') 
     WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM authors WHERE author='$rec_fic_author')") 
or die("cannot insert author");
```

here author is the name of table

```
authorID (pk)
author $rec_fic_author is _POST variable
```

Comment: Syntax error.  MySQL `INSERT ... VALUES()` does not accept a WHERE clause.

Comment: @ pilcrow- which WHERE clause it's not accepting?Make sure that you ave given correct Field names...Check out for Capital-small letters..

Comment: The first WHERE is rejected.  (Wrong or wrongly cased identifiers, on [platforms where that matters](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html), would not cause a *syntax* error in any case.)  Your `INSERT ... VALUES (...) WHERE ...` is simply not a valid MySQL query.